# Site name is not visible in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

We now have a themed chat room and it looks great! Mostly. The site logo on the lower right, however, is invisible:

[image]

Specifically:

[image]

This is on firefox 37.0 running on a 64bit Debian.

Comment: And I am seeing the Beta logo still.

Comment: For me, it is on the lower right, but also broken (more specifically, the text has almost the same colour as the background). Firefox 38.0.1 on WIndows 7.

Comment: Now same here. The beta logo is gone. I am also running firefox 38.0.1 on 64bit Fedora 21

Answer (score 1):

I have just pushed a fix to give the logo a lighter background color, so you have a chance of seeing it. This will go out with the next chat build (some time today). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this as soon as the fix comes along.